# Circular reference issue with Spring + Hibernate + JPA multi tenancy implementation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I am having issues with setting up multi-tenancy support for my web application with a separate database approach using Spring + JPA + Hibernate.

I have tried the Hibernate way using my own implementations of `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` and `AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider`, and the Spring one using `AbstractRoutingDataSource`. I'll use the `AbstractRoutingDataSource` solution, that I named `UserRoutingDataSource`, to explain my problem.

What I am trying to achieve is the following :

1. I have a "master" database with all the data concerning the users and their databases
2. When a user logs in I save his database id in a session scoped bean named `UserSession`
3. My `UserRoutingDataSource`'s `targetDataSources` needs to be filled with datasources representing all the databases of my master database's `CustomDatabases` table.
4. When a connection is needed, my `UserRoutingDataSource`'s `determineCurrentLookupKey` needs to retrieve the database id from the user's `UserSession` instance.

In both cases (Hibernate way / Spring way) I end up with a circular reference exception. The issue arises when I try to autowire my `CustomDatabasesDAO` and my `UserSession` in `UserRoutingDataSource`.

This is the exception I get :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [MyApp/webapp/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userRoutingDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRoutingDataSource' defined in class path resource [MyApp/webapp/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [myApp.java.data.dao.Global.CustomDatabasesDAO]: : Error creating bean with name 'customDatabasesDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEntityManagerFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customDatabasesDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEntityManagerFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:828)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRoutingDataSource' defined in class path resource [MyApp/webapp/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [myApp.java.data.dao.Global.CustomDatabasesDAO]: : Error creating bean with name 'customDatabasesDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEntityManagerFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customDatabasesDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEntityManagerFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customDatabasesDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEntityManagerFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEntityManagerFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findNamedEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:556)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:538)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:707)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:680)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
    ... 46 more
```

What I don't understand is why I get this exception when my `CustomDatabasesDAO` doesn't have a single reference to `userEntityManagerFactory`. The only relevant thing that I can think of in `CustomDatabasesDAO` is my call to the master database's entityManager :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "masterEntityManagerFactory")
private EntityManager masterEntityManager;
```

For more context, here are my `UserRoutingDataSource` file and the relevant parts from my application context file.

### UserRoutingDataSource

```
public class UserRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    
    /*private CustomDatabasesDAO customDatabasesDAO;
    
    @Autowired
    public void setCustomDatabasesDAO(final CustomDatabasesDAO customDatabasesDAO)
    {
        this.customDatabasesDAO = customDatabasesDAO;
    }*/
    
    @Autowired
    private UserSession session;

    /*@Autowired
    public void setUserSession(final UserSession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }*/

    @Autowired
    public UserRoutingDataSource(CustomDatabasesDAO customDatabasesDAO) {
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        
        for(CustomDatabases database : customDatabasesDAO.findDatabasesByDeleted(0))
        {
            // All the information necessary for the datasource will eventually be retrieved from the database variable
            DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            datasource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            datasource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=" + database.getCdboAliasName() + ";");
            datasource.setUsername("username");
            datasource.setPassword("password");
            
            targetDataSources.put(String.valueOf(database.getCdboDatabaseId()), datasource);
        }
        
        setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    }

    
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return session.getCdboDatabaseId();
    }
}
```

### Application context

```
/*<!--<bean id="currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl" class="myApp.java.config.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl" />
    <bean id="multiTenantConnectionProvider" class="myApp.java.config.MultiTenantConnectionProvider" />-->*/
    
    <bean id="masterDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myDatabase;" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="masterEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="masterDataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="myApp.java.data.model" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">true</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="userRoutingDataSource" class="myApp.java.config.UserRoutingDataSource">
        <property name="targetDataSources">
            <map />
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="userEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="userRoutingDataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="myApp.java.data.model" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.use_outer_join" value="true" />
            /*<!--<entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value-ref="currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl" />
            <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value-ref="multiTenantConnectionProvider" />
            <entry key="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE" />-->*/
         </map>
      </property>
   </bean>
    
    <!-- Transaction managers -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    
    <bean id="masterTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="masterEntityManagerFactory" />
        <qualifier value="master" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="userTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="userEntityManagerFactory" />
        <qualifier value="user" />
    </bean>
```

I have tried so many things that I am not sure if I still understand how dependency injection works. And I have no idea what I might be missing.

Thanks for you help.

## SOLUTION :

I solved my issue thanks to Roman's answer. I also gave up on the idea of using my session scoped bean to determine my current lookup key and I use my Spring Security authentication instead. When a user logs in I do the following :

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(), authorities);
HashMap<String, Object> details = new HashMap<String, Object>();
details.put("databaseId", session.getCdboDatabaseId());
newAuth.setDetails(details);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
```

The important part being the `setDetails(details)` on my user's `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

Here is the current state of my (working) configuration :

### UserRoutingDataSource

```
@Component
public class UserRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Autowired
    public UserRoutingDataSource(CustomDatabasesDAO customDatabasesDAO) {
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        
        for(CustomDatabases database : customDatabasesDAO.findDatabasesByDeleted(0))
        {
            DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            datasource.setDriverClassName(database.getCdboDriverName());
            datasource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://"+database.getCdboServer()+":"+database.getCdboPort()+";databaseName="+database.getCdboAliasName() + ";");
            datasource.setUsername(database.getCdboUserName());
            datasource.setPassword(database.getCdboPassword());
            
            targetDataSources.put(database.getCdboDatabaseId(), datasource);
        }
        
        /*
         * This default datasource is necessary because for some reason (Hibernate, JPA related ?) the routing datasource 
         * calls the "determineCurrentLookupKey()" on startup which returned null ("default" now) because there is no Authentication at startup yet.
         */
        targetDataSources.put("default", new DriverManagerDataSource());    
        setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        afterPropertiesSet();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        
        if (auth != null && auth.getDetails() instanceof Map)
        {
            HashMap<String, Object> details = (HashMap<String, Object>) auth.getDetails();
            return details.get("databaseId");
        }
        
        return "default";
    }
}
```

### Application context

```
<bean id="masterDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myDatabase;" />
        <property name="username" value="myUser" />
        <property name="password" value="myPassword" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="masterEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="masterEntityManagerFactory" />
      <property name="dataSource" ref="masterDataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="myApp.java.data.model" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">true</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="userEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="userEntityManagerFactory" />
      <property name="dataSource" ref="userRoutingDataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="myApp.java.data.model" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.use_outer_join" value="true" />
         </map>
      </property>
   </bean>
    
    <!-- Transaction managers -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    
    <bean id="masterTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="masterEntityManagerFactory" />
        <qualifier value="master" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="userTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="userEntityManagerFactory" />
        <qualifier value="user" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring iterates over all `EntityManagerFactory`s inside of `EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory()` to find out the factory with the property `persistenceUnitName` value equals to `@PersistenceUnit`'s attribute `unitName` value. Only if no candidate has been found the bean with the name of `unitName` value will be used. Therefore `userEntityManagerFactory` gets instantiated during this process.

As a workaround you could try to make use of regular `@Autowired` instead of `@PersistenceUnit` in `CustomDatabasesDAO` class.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me understand what was wrong with my configuration.
To clarify, I am using `@PersistenceContext` which returns a `EntityManager` as opposed to `@PersistenceUnit` which returns a `EntityManagerFactory`. For this reason your suggestion of using `@Autowired` instead of `@PersistenceContext` didn't work. But it lead me to fix my problem by adding
`<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="masterEntityManagerFactory" />` to my `masterEntityManagerFactory` in my application context. I am not sure I understand why it works but it does. See my edited post for my current config.

Comment: Great. It works because the iteration inside of `EntityManagerFactoryUtils` stopped on `masterEntityManagerFactory` and didn't reach the `userEntityManagerFactory`.